# MAEN app with passport.js not sending session cookie when secure is set to true

Tags: node.js, cookies, passport.js, session-cookies, credentials

I am using passport.js to authenticate.

Cors: `app.use(cors({ origin: ENV, credentials: true }));`

Under ENV I have my fronted url.

Session and rest config:

```
app.set("trust proxy", 1);
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "wonttellyou",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
      path: "/",
      httpOnly: true,
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
      sameSite: "none"
      secure: true,
    },
  })
);
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

I've deployed front on vercel, and backend on back4app and everything works fine when i'm using firefox which allows secure flag set to false. Chrome is not so polite and I have to set secure to true. With that change my backend is not sending cookie to the front, but i can see that session cookie exist cuz `req.sessionStore.sessions` returns me session made by loggin in.

> izFjwfnGUAVrRSJU1eWJqzOTEeGI-Cmz':
> '{"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":86400000,"expires":"2023-09-03T16:19:15.519Z","secure":true,"httpOnly":true,"path":"/","sameSite":"none"},"passport":{"user":"643026b271b721a7aa08f4fd"}}

Things I have done:

1. Changes in cors: origin, exposedHeaders
2. Changes in express session config - multiple different changes.
3. Sending cookies via res.cookie - it works
4. Check if my requests are withCredentials (they are)
5. Lie down and cry a lot

Comment: If you set secure: true then, the cookie will  be sent to the server by the browser over https, and not plain http. So, in the ENV have you used https:// instead of http:// ?

Comment: Yes, i've used https

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? If not, I recommend you create a support ticket, so that, their support team can assist you with it.